# Unable to access counter after gets updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to start an `interval` by clicking on a button.
Here the `interval` gets started but, I can't access the value of `counter`. because when counter gets equal to 5, the interval should be stoped.

Here is the example:

```
let interval = null;
const stateReducer = (state, value) => value;

function App(props) {

  const [counter, setCounter] = useReducer(stateReducer, 0);

  const increment = () => {

    interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(counter + 1);
      if (counter === 5) clearInterval(interval);
      console.log(counter);
    }, 1000);

  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{counter}</p>
      <button className="App" onClick={increment}>
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can run this code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-it6vt)

Comment: This is unclear. Could you please explain what's the expected behavior?

Comment: @Muhammad are you looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58508823/6544460 ?

Comment: @Dupocas, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. change `const stateReducer = (state, value) => value;` to `const
   stateReducer = (state, value) => state+value;`
2. make a variable `let current_counter = 0;` outside function
3. Change your increment function like this

```
current_counter = counter;
const increment = () => {
   interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(1);
      if (current_counter === 5) clearInterval(interval);
      console.log(current_counter);
    }, 1000);
};
```

1. **`Done`**

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

let interval = null;
let current_counter = 0;
const stateReducer = (state, value) => value;

function App(props) {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useReducer(stateReducer, 0);
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(status){
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
          setCounter(counter + 1);
        }, 1000)
        return ()=>{
          clearInterval(interval)
        };
    }

  })
  const increment = () => {
    setStatus(!status)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{counter}</p>
      <button className="App" onClick={increment}>
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: thank you, but this is not a good solution as I useEffect called in every update.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few problems.

**Your reducer declaration**

```
const initialState = { value : 0 }

const reducer = (state, action) =>{
    if(action.type === 'INCREMENT') return { value : state.value + 1 }

    return state
}
```

**How you're setting your reducer**

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
```

**How you're dispatching your action**

`intervals` are imperative code, you can't consistently declare an `interval` inside a React's handler without worrying about closure. You could use the `click` only to flag that the interval should start and handle all imperative code inside an `useEffect`. Here is a working example

```
const initialState = { value: 0 };
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "INCREMENT")
    return {
      value: state.value + 1
    };
};
function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;
    if (clicked) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" });
      }, 1000);
    }
    if (state.value > 4) clearInterval(interval);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [clicked, state]);

  return <button onClick={() => setClicked(true)}>{state.value}</button>;
}
```

[image: Edit holy-grass-22y29]

If your curious about closures and how react handle imperative code take a look on this [awesome article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) from Dan Abramov (the most detailed explanation about effects out there).

Comment: Thank you, but here use effect called on every update and new Interval reference gets create. because I just put a simple example, while my main code is a large code.

Comment: Not it isn't. It's only called when `state` and `clicked` changes. The answer you choose will cause problems later. You simply don't declare imperative code inside a handler

Comment: Thank you the question I ticked, worked for me as well. but I don't know about its performance.

Comment: Peformance isn't the only issue here. You're never cleaning the interval if the component gets unmounted for example. Try to mount/unmount your component after clicking the button. Your app will crash. Seriously the answer that worked for you is in fact a bad advice. Closures are messy inside intervals, updates don't get batched. use `useEffect` to handle imperative code

Comment: Also there is another useEffect which on unmount I am clearing the interval

Comment: Good. Always clean your intervals before unmounting